# Copy data/File from Windows to Linux machine or HDFS

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, bigdata

I am working on Big data and want to fetch data/files from a file system present in remote machine not from any databases i.e to copy files from remote linux / windows machine to **hdfs**. Please help me.

Comment: You mean copy files from remote linux machine to local linux machine?

Comment: copy file's from remote linux/windows machine to local machine or hdfs.

Comment: mention that in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy file from your local file to a remote file system and vice versa by using

> scp commands 
>   *scp [Options] [[User@]From_Host:]Source_File [[User@]To_Host:][Destination_File]*

Comment: can i give my hdfs path in `source_file` ?

Comment: yes, you can give hdfs path in order to export the file to that path but before that you need to write as such *username@hostname:/hdfs_path* Also, if it is hdfs,then you can just use *hdfs dfs -put your_local_file hdfs_path* to upload your file to hadoop

Comment: i tried this scp command and it is working fine between linux systesm but it is not working between linux and window's system.

Comment: you can use filezilla for this purpose, here is the link https://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please upvote if you liked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `Hue`. It's a very useful tool for this.
Follow this link for more details : http://gethue.com/

Enter into the File Browser in Hue, and click on "Add files" button then you can upload your files into `HDFS`

Comment: i am using cloudera cdh 5.7 it already has `Hue` but how to move file from windows machine using `Hue` ?

Comment: Enter into the File Browser in Hue, and click on "Add files" button

Comment: it is showing me my linux machine local file system. No option to select from windows file system.

Comment: you can upload file from your windows file system

Comment: Thanks for your help ! is there any way to automate this process ?